# How to create a static array of strings?

Tags: arrays, string, static, rust

> **Note** This question contains syntax that predates Rust 1.0. The code is invalid, but the concepts are still relevant.

How do you create a global static array of strings in Rust?

For integers, this compiles:

```
static ONE:u8 = 1;
static TWO:u8 = 2;
static ONETWO:[&'static u8, ..2] = [&ONE, &TWO];
```

But I can't get something similar for strings to compile:

```
static STRHELLO:&'static str = "Hello";
static STRWORLD:&'static str = "World";
static ARR:[&'static str, ..2] = [STRHELLO,STRWORLD]; // Error: Cannot refer to the interior of another static
```

Comment: This code in the rust playpen: http://is.gd/IPkdU4

Answer (score 108, accepted):

This is a stable alternative for Rust 1.0 and every subsequent version:

```
const BROWSERS: &'static [&'static str] = &["firefox", "chrome"];
```

Comment: Accepting without testing since there seems to be a consensus on this. (I'm not using Rust currently) Thanks!

Comment: You can drop the `'static` lifetime specifiers `const BROWSERS: &[&str] = &["firefox", "chrome"];`

Answer (score 8):

There are two related concepts and keywords in Rust: const and static:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/constant-items.html

For most use cases, including this one, const is more appropriate, since mutation is not allowed, and the compiler may inline const items.

```
const STRHELLO:&'static str = "Hello";
const STRWORLD:&'static str = "World";
const ARR:[&'static str, ..2] = [STRHELLO,STRWORLD];
```

Note, there is some out-of-date documentation out there that doesn't mention the newer const, including Rust by Example.

Comment: The documentation moved to [a new place](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items.html#constant-items).

Comment: There is a typo in the example code, the first `,` should have been `;` as in `const ARR:[&'static str; ..2] = [STRHELLO,STRWORLD];`

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do it nowadays is:

```rs
const A: &'static str = "Apples";
const B: &'static str = "Oranges";
const AB: [&'static str; 2] = [A, B]; // or ["Apples", "Oranges"]
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the compiler infer the length (2) from the number of elements listed?

Comment: @nishanthshanmugham Unstable https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/85077 `#![feature(generic_arg_infer)]`

Answer (score 4):

Just used this to allocate a small POC level for a game in Rust

```
const LEVEL_0: &'static [&'static [i32]] = &[
    &[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    &[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    &[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    &[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    &[1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 1],
    &[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    &[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    &[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    &[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    &[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
];
```

And loaded using the following function

```
pub fn load_stage(&mut self, ctx: &mut Context, level: usize) {
    let levels = vec![LEVEL_0];

    for (i, row) in levels[level].iter().enumerate() {
        for (j, col) in row.iter().enumerate() {
            if *col == 1 {
                self.board.add_block(
                    ctx,
                    Vector2::<f32>::new(j as f32, i as f32),
                    self.cell_size,
                );
            }
```

`Note: The code above is slightly incomplete, it's just to give some context to the answer`

For strings you can use something like:

```
const ENEMIES: &'static [&'static str] = &["monster", "ghost"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays You can write it without indirection through a pointer:

```
const ONETWO: [u8;2]   = [1, 2];
const ARRAY:  [&str;2] = ["Hello", "World"];

fn main() {
    println!("{} {}", ONETWO[0], ONETWO[1]);  // 1 2
    println!("{} {}", ARRAY[0], ARRAY[1]);  // Hello World
}
```

---

Thanks to static lifetime elision, you usually don’t have to explicitly use

`'static` like in:

```
const ARRAY: [&'static str;2] = ["Hello", "World"];
```