# What is the difference between a constant and a static variable and which should I choose?

Tags: variables, rust, static, constants

I know this from [RFC 246](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0246-const-vs-static.md):

> - **constants** declare *constant values*. These represent a value, not a memory address. This is the most common thing one would reach for and would replace `static` as we know it today in almost all  cases.
> - **statics** declare *global variables*. These represent a memory   address.  They would be rarely used: the primary use cases are global locks, global atomic counters, and interfacing with legacy C  libraries.

I don't know what is actually different between the two when I try to maintain a table.

Which one should I choose?

Comment: "statics declare global variables. These represent a memory address.", to be clear, this is totally wrong.

Comment: @Stargateur Check https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0246-const-vs-static.md.

Comment: That a very bad choice of word.

Comment: @Stargateur Uh, how do you express that?  ^ ^

Comment: These represent a value like const, https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0ff8d6a83ae3c458a226606e95bec96a&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

### Mutability

A `const`ant in Rust is immutable. You neither can reassign nor modify it:

```rust
struct Foo(u32);

const FOO: Foo = Foo(5);
const mut FOO: Foo = Foo(5); // illegal

fn main() {
    FOO = Foo(1); //illegal
    FOO.0 = 2; //illegal
}
```

A `static` variable *can* be mutable and therefore can either be modified or reassigned. Note that writing/modifying a global `static` variable is unsafe and therefore needs an `unsafe` block:

```rust
struct Foo(u32);
static FOO: Foo = Foo(5);
static mut FOO_MUT: Foo = Foo(3);

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        FOO = Foo(1); //illegal
        FOO.0 = 2; //illegal

        FOO_MUT = Foo(1);
        FOO_MUT.0 = 2;
    }
}
```

### Occurrences

When you compile a binary, all `const` "occurrences" (where you use that `const` in your source code) will be replaced by that value directly.

`static`s will have a dedicated section in your binary where they will be placed (the *BSS section*, see [Where are static variables stored in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93039/where-are-static-variables-stored-in-c-and-c) for further information).

---

All in all, stick to a `const` whenever possible. When not possible, because you need to initialize a variable later in the program of with non-`const` methods, use [`lazy_static!`](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static).

### Interior mutability

While both `const` and `static` can use interior mutability you should never ever do it with a const. Here's an example

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicU32, Ordering};

static STATIC: AtomicU32 = AtomicU32::new(0);
const CONST: AtomicU32 = AtomicU32::new(0);

fn print() {
    println!("static: {}", STATIC.load(Ordering::Relaxed));
    println!("const:  {}", CONST.load(Ordering::Relaxed));
}

fn main() {
    STATIC.store(3, Ordering::Relaxed);
    CONST.store(3, Ordering::Relaxed);

    print();
}
```

This compiles fine without any warnings, but leads to unwanted behavoir. Output:

```
static: 3
const:  0
```

When using clippy, it will show the two following warnings:

```
warning: a `const` item should never be interior mutable
 --> src/main.rs:4:1
  |
4 | const CONST: AtomicU32 = AtomicU32::new(0);
  | -----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  | |
  | make this a static item (maybe with lazy_static)
  |
  = note: `#[warn(clippy::declare_interior_mutable_const)]` on by default
  = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#declare_interior_mutable_const

warning: a `const` item with interior mutability should not be borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:8:27
  |
8 |     println!("const: {}", CONST.load(Ordering::Relaxed));
  |                           ^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(clippy::borrow_interior_mutable_const)]` on by default
  = help: assign this const to a local or static variable, and use the variable here
  = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#borrow_interior_mutable_const

warning: a `const` item with interior mutability should not be borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
13 |     CONST.store(3, Ordering::Relaxed);
   |     ^^^^^
   |
   = help: assign this const to a local or static variable, and use the variable here
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#borrow_interior_mutable_const
```

Comment: @TimDiekmann while I agree with the spirit of your advice, I think it's too high-level. There are cases where a `const` would *work* but give terrible performance compared to a `static`, such as [the code that OP links to](https://github.com/kennytm/qrcode-rust/blob/d10dad26284fc938c470236b7221460e1a5f99e9/src/ec.rs#L238-L273).

Comment: @TimDiekmann sure, but you quoted it in the comments and thus seem to agree with the veracity of the statement and agree with the guidance. hellow will see all comments on their answer; I have to mention you directly.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks to you point out that. Should I use `static` while maintaining some large tables such as that?

Comment: @AurevoirXavier there's no blanket answer for that question. You need to use profiling to see if the change is worth it, assuming both types work for a given situation.

Comment: I think following link (even "outdated") can be useful -> https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.29.2/book/first-edition/const-and-static.html#which-construct-should-i-use

Comment: And `static` variables must be `Sync`, which is not needed for `const` vars. Though this can be seen as a result of that `Occurrence` difference.

Answer (score 22):

### Rust `static` vs `const`

**`const`:**

- Have no fixed address in memory
- They’re inlined to each place which uses them, this means they are put directly into the binary on the places which use them.
- Usually faster runtime but bigger executable file because it doesn't have to look up an address like `static`

**`static`:**

- Have a fixed address in memory
- Their value is loaded from this fixed address each place which uses them.
- Usually slower runtime because we need to perform the extra instruction of loading the data from the fixed address. However this could result in a smaller executable file (only when it is used frequently) because it doesn't have to have multiple copies of the value baked into the executable.

**Example:**

```
    static CDF: i32 = 100;
    const ABC: i32 = 50;

    fn main() {
        println!("{}", CDF); // compiler will put in a load instruction here for the static address
        println!("{}", ABC); // compiler will put the value 50 here directly
    
        // statics can be mutable
        static mut HI: &str = "hi";
    
        // however using mut static is unsafe
        unsafe {
            HI = "HITHERE";
        }
    
        unsafe {
            println!("{}", HI);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 18):

There's not much practical difference if your variable isn't intended to change.

Constants are inlined at compilation, which means they're copied to every location they're used, and thus are usually more efficient, while statics refer to a unique location in memory and are more like global variables.

Constants are... constant while statics, while still global, can be mutable.

Answer (score -3):

The main purpose of `static` is to allow functions to control an internal value that is remembered across calls, but not be accessible by the main application code. It is similar to Class variables as opposed to Instance variables in other languages. Also C and PHP and many other languages have this concept.

Example: you want to track how many times a function is called and have a way of resetting the internal counter:

```rust
fn counter(reset: bool) -> i32 {
    static mut Count: i32 = 0;

    unsafe {
        if reset {
            Count = 0;
        }    
        Count += 1;
        return Count;
    }
}

println!("{}",counter(true));
println!("{}",counter(false));
println!("{}",counter(false));
//println!("{}", Count); // Illegal
```

Comment: While this is *one* way of using `static`, I don't think I'd call it the "main purpose". Note that the Rust sense of `static` is broader than the use of `static` inside C functions, since it is also used to create global variables outside of functions (C doesn't use `static` for this purpose, instead making it do double-duty as a linkage modifier).