# How to use a once_cell::sync::Lazy in another once_cell::sync::Lazy?

Tags: rust, synchronization, lazy-initialization

I want to use Rust and [once_cell](https://crates.io/crates/once_cell) to implement some static const struct instance, and one static const vector contains these static struct instances.

Here's the sample code:

```
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;

pub struct Kind {
  name: String,
  value: i32,
}

impl Kind {
  pub fn new(name: &str, value: i32) -> Kind {
    Kind {name: String::from(name), value}
  }
}

const HYBRID: Lazy<Kind> = Lazy::new(|| Kind::new("a", 1));
const BOND: Lazy<Kind> = Lazy::new(|| Kind::new("b", 2));
// other instances

static KINDS: Lazy<Vec<Kind>> = Lazy::new(|| {
  vec![
    HYBRID,
    BOND,
    // other instances,
  ]
});
```

Here's the compiler error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/quant/fund/data/fund_info.rs:50:9
   |
50 |         HYBRID,
   |         ^^^^^^ expected struct `Kind`, found struct `once_cell::sync::Lazy`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Kind`
              found struct `once_cell::sync::Lazy<Kind>`
```

How should I get the real `Kind` inside `Lazy` ?

Answer (score 6):

One option is just to create them there:

```rust
static KINDS: Lazy<Vec<Kind>> = Lazy::new(|| {
    vec![
        Kind::new("a", 1),
        Kind::new("b", 2),
        // other instances,
    ]
});
```

But the above way will not allow you to use the values separately, using their statics. If you do want to do that, you can store references (note that you should use `static` and not `const` for the values, see [What is the difference between a constant and a static variable and which should I choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52751597/what-is-the-difference-between-a-constant-and-a-static-variable-and-which-should)). Since `Lazy` impls `Deref`, you can just use `&*`. Or you can use [`Lazy::force()`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/sync/struct.Lazy.html#method.force) if you want to be more explicit.

```rust
static HYBRID: Lazy<Kind> = Lazy::new(|| Kind::new("a", 1));
static BOND: Lazy<Kind> = Lazy::new(|| Kind::new("b", 2));
// other instances

static KINDS: Lazy<Vec<&Kind>> = Lazy::new(|| {
    vec![
        Lazy::force(&HYBRID),
        &*BOND,
        // other instances,
    ]
});
```

Or, if you need owned values, clone them:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Kind { /* ... */ }

static HYBRID: Lazy<Kind> = Lazy::new(|| Kind::new("a", 1));
static BOND: Lazy<Kind> = Lazy::new(|| Kind::new("b", 2));
// other instances

static KINDS: Lazy<Vec<Kind>> = Lazy::new(|| {
    vec![
        HYBRID.clone(),
        BOND.clone(),
        // other instances,
    ]
});
```

Comment: store references in KINDS lazy vector should work for me, thanks!